# mysql union and order not working

Tags: php, mysql, union, fetch

I am trying to combine all the results as i go through the loop

```
$result = ....;
$finalresult = 0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $clubID = $row['clubID'];
    $finalresult = mysql_query('"'.$finalresult.'" UNION ALL SELECT * FROM events WHERE clubID = "'.$clubID.'"');
}
```

However, this isn't working. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: You're better off writing each query to an array, then using `implode()` to merge them all together at the end. Alternatively, you can also use `WHERE clubID IN ()` clause, to just do one single query?

Comment: is finalresult containing query string ?

Comment: @RajeevRanjan no finalresult is containing the result of the select, i just initialized it before with the value 0

Comment: @andrewsi if you don't mind can u give me a specific example?

Comment: Please, **DO NOT** use string concatenation to compose queries. You **must** [properly escape](http://bobby-tables.com/php) any and all values being put into your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$clubIDs = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $clubIDs[] = $row['clubID'];
}

$finalresult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events WHERE clubID IN (" . implode(',', $clubIDs) . ")");
```

It's generating a list of clubIDs from your previous query, and putting them in an array. Then, it's using that array to generate an IN clause, and retrieving all the data in one go.

A couple of caveats - this will fail if there are no valid club IDs, so you'll want to add some error checking.

Secondly, mysql_* is deprecated in PHP 5.5, so you should look at using mysqli_* or PDO instead - they're both much more secure.